# MySQL update table with data from another table based on field

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks like this

```
 leads
 name         zip          city      county     state
 Bill         84058
 Susan        90001

 FullUSZipCodes
 ZipCode       City        County       State
 84058         Orem        Utah         Utah
 90001         Los Angeles South        California
```

As you can see, in the leads database the city, count and state are empty, i'm trying to merge the data so that the first table would look like this:

```
 leads
 name         zip          city      county     state
 Bill         84058        Orem      Utah       Utah
 Susan        90001        Los Angeles South    California
```

This is the first query I tried:

```
UPDATE leads SET leads.county = FullUSZipCodes.County WHERE leads.zip = FullUSZipCodes.ZipCode
```

which didn't work, and here is the 2nd query:

```
UPDATE leads INNER JOIN FullUSZipCodes ON leads.zip = FullUSZipCodes.ZipCode SET leads.county = FullUSZipCodes.County, leads.city = FullUSZipCodes.City, leads.state = FullUSZipCodes.State
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second query looks like it should work, but I would write it slightly differently:

```
UPDATE leads t1
INNER JOIN FullUSZipCodes t2
    ON t1.zip = t2.ZipCode
SET
    t1.city = t2.City,
    t1.county = t2.County,
    t1.state = t2.State
WHERE
    t1.city IS NULL OR t1.county IS NULL OR t1.state IS NULL;
```

If the `leads` table has a lot of records, and performance is a concern, you can try adding a `WHERE` clause to the update query which targets only those records which are missing one or more pieces of address information.  I think there is nothing wrong with always updating all three columns together, because typically this information tends to be grouped together.

Comment: That is the 2nd query I tried, it just kept processing the query but didn't seem to ever finish

Comment: You can also add a `WHERE` clause to try and target records which are missing data.

Comment: About 50,000 records, all of them are missing the data

Comment: Possibly, it’s been running the query for 20min I️ knew it would take time, didn’t realize it would take that long